# Populate option values in form from .txt file

Tags: javascript, php, forms, select

I have a form that I am creating for basic time submission at a company. However, I need to design one part so that the owner can simply load up a .txt file or an excel document or something similar and replace and edit names real quick for the drop down field.

The current code:

```
<select name="entry.44832674" id="entry_44832674" aria-required="true" required="">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
          <option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
          <option value="Option 3">Option 3</option>
          <option value="Option 4">Option 4</option>
          <option value="Option 5">Option 5</option>
        </select>
```

Is this possible to perform with php or javascript of some sort? Would like to keep this as simple as possible as the owner does not have time to mess with code. If possible to create a simple .txt file in the format of

Option 1
Option 2
Option 3
Option 4
Option 5

and then the owner can add or remove names when needed that would be awesome. I have found many solutions for things, but could not find an answer for this one.

Comment: For one thing, I doubt this is valid `name="entry.44832674"` use an underscore.

Comment: or you can use database to store those options .. load and concatenate it ... then echo it in PHP ..

Comment: Using a DB will be much easier than having a script go through to pick a specific spot in the file to edit. You're facing a literal nightmare if you go this route. If you do plan to use this method, make sure you use file locking. I say this from experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
<select>
<option value=""></option>

<?php
$options=nl2br(file_get_contents("optionsTextFile.txt"));
$options=explode("<br>",$options);

for($i=0;$i<count($options);$i++)
  {
  echo "<option value='".$options[$i]."'>".$options[$i]."</option>";
  }
?>

</select>
```

Comment: This worked out perfectly for me and I think is all I need. I simply replaced <br> with ; and will later see what the owner wants to use instead to be easy for him. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done php for like 10 years, so please excuse if i missed something but this should illustrate the essentials (i just looked at the manual and sorta tried to piece it together right)

```
somefile.txt
------------------
value1|some text 1
value2|some text 2

<select>
<option value="--">--</option>

<?php
$trimmed = file("somefile.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$length  = count($trimmed);

for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $options = explode("|", $trimmed[i]);

    echo "<option value=\"" . $options[0] . "\">". $options[1] ."</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```